# Killing parent process through child

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I was tasked with implementing this myshell program which mirrors Linux shell. This is in the scope of an introductory Operating Systems course at my university. They provided us the basic shell code and asked us to tamper with it.

One of the exercises is to implement an exit command which terminated the custom shell. I did this using strcmp. However I feel this is a very hacky solution - feels like cheating.

Here's the source code:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char buf[1024];
    char* args[256];
    pid_t pid;

    for( ; ; ){
        char* command;
        fprintf(stdout, "$ ");
        if((command = fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) == NULL){
            break;
        }
        command[strlen(buf) -1] = '\0';
        //saving commands to a memory file so I can 
        //print them out later on with tail (through 
        //myhistory)
        FILE* f = fopen("mem.txt", "a");
        fwrite(command, sizeof(char), strlen(command), f);
        fputc('\n', f);
        fclose(f);
        int i = 0;
        do{
            if(i == 0) args[i] = strtok(command, " ");
            else args[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
            i++;
        }while(args[i-1] != NULL);
        //hacky exit command I'm trying to improve on
        if(!strcmp(args[0], "exit")) exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        if((pid = fork()) == -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: cant fork command: %s", 
                argv[0], strerror(errno));
            continue;
        } else if (pid == 0){
                execvp(args[0], args);
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: couldn't exec %s: %s\n", 
                    argv[0], buf, strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }  
        if((pid = waitpid(pid, NULL, 0)) < 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: waitpid error: %s\n",
                argv[0], strerror(errno));
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I wrote the exit command like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(){
    kill(getpid(), 0);
}
```

however this doesn't help since I'm just killing the child. How could I kill the parent through the child? Yes, I'm aware I could pass the parent PID to the exit command and terminate it that way, but something tells me there's a cleaner solution that doesn't require hard coding control flow logic.

Comment: To me, an external command which kills its parent seems like the ugly solution. A shell should control its own death. For one thing, it might have some cleanup it wants to do (like saving history). But you could do it if you wanted to. `man getppid`. However, there are other commands which *must* be builtins. (`cd` is the one which comes up here the most, but there are several.) So the shell needs to have the concept of builtins, and `exit` is just one of several.

Answer (score 6):

In "real" shell, commands like `exit` is a ["shell built-in"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html). They are not external commands that starts another program, but executed internally by the shell.

You can implement those through various means, strcmp, dictionary, etc, but they are essentially just glorified version of what you're currently doing. So, yeah, keep doing what you're doing.

Comment: thanks. it just felt a little non-challant to do it this way, but if that's the way that's the way I guess ^^'